# WinSock Send Function not sending

Tags: c++, iostream, winsock

so I'm writing an IRC bot in C++, and I wrote my own send function

```
    int Send(char* MessageToSend) {
    initResult = send(bobSocket, MessageToSend, (int)strlen(MessageToSend), 0);
    if (initResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(bobSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and whenever I use it in my sendmessage function (which loop checks for messages and then runs all the input to send) kind of like this

```
while(1 > 0) {
 string b;
 cin >> b;
 char* INPUT = const_cast<char*>(b.c_str());
 Send(b);
}
```

but when I put PRIVMSG ##channel :test into the console, I don't see anything on the other client, so, can anybody like help? I'm fairly new to stackoverflow, and C++, so any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So it prints the send failed message? Or not? And bobSocket is a valid, properly connected socket?

Comment: @JasonC no it doesn't print the failed message, and bobSocket is a valid, properly connected socket, it connects to IRC registers nick and joins the channel I want it to, but the input just doesn't send to IRC server.

Comment: Are you sure its not sending it to the server? Could it be that its just no in the right format? IF you're managing to connect to the server, and join a room, my bets would be that you're sending a wrongly formatted command.

Comment: what does `send` return?

Comment: If it didn't print the 'failed' message, it didn't fail. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @RichardChambers There is no such thing as flushing a socket.

Comment: @BenCummins No, it's just not sending to the server, the format is correct, it's just not sending, it's not erroring, it just isn't sending.

Comment: @EJP I don't know why it doesn't prent a failed message, but it just isn't sending.

Comment: @Serge send doesn't return anything unless it fails.

Comment: you are incorrect, send always returns something.

Comment: how do I see what it returns?

Comment: printf("%d\n", initResult);

Comment: @Serge it returns the number of character in each word, so if I did something like this PRIVMSG ##channel :hello there it would be 7 9 7

Comment: If it returns a positive integer, it is sending. Clearly either the problem is at the receiving end or you aren't sending the correct data. Note that if it really returns 7, 9, 7 it means you are sending one line in three different sends, and you're losing the internal space, and sending the trailing newline. So the problem may be that you're parsing the input incorrectly.

Comment: I did not ask what it would return. I asked what it actually does return when you see no input on the other side

Comment: it returns a positive integer, well multiple positive integers

Comment: Sigh. We know that. We are asking for the *actual value(s)*. Saying 'would be 7 9 7' is understood to mean that you are making a prediction, not supplying actual values from a real test.

Comment: As @EJP commented, check the receiving party

Comment: Ok I sent PRIVMSG ##channel :hello and it returned 7 9 7, I went on to print what it was sending, and it printed each word in a new line, which would mean that I'm parsing this incorrectly, but to be quite frank, I don't know any other way to parse it other than const_cast, so, yeah.

Comment: So, no. `const_cast` is not a parse. The `>>` operator is what is doing the parsing into words. You shouldn't be parsing *at all.* You should be *reading lines*.

Comment: k how would I do that @EJP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `send()` returns 7, 9, 7 for `PRIVMSG ##channel :hello`, it means you are sending that one line in three different sends, and you're losing the internal spaces, and sending the trailing newline. So the problem may be that you're parsing the input incorrectly. What you are actually sending is:

```
PRIVMSG (7 bytes)
##channel (9 bytes)
:hello\n (7 bytes)
```

and note again that you have lost the internal spaces.

I believe you should be reading lines from the console, not words.

And note that I am starting this answer with 'if', as your responses to comments have been far from clear.

Comment: sorry for the unclearness, im fairly new and very bad at describing, but, could u give me another way 2 parse than char_cast